# How to define input data for stbi_info_from_memory?

Tags: c++, c++17, stb-image

I am trying to extract image data info from `stbi_info_from_memory`. Not sure why I am getting an unknown data type error.

Please find a test below:

```
    // 8x8 checkerboard pattern
    unsigned char data[] = {
        0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00,
        0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00,
        0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF,
        0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF,
        0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF};

    int length = sizeof(data) / sizeof(unsigned char);
    int width = -1 , height = -1, channels = -1;
    EXPECT_TRUE(
        stbi_info_from_memory(data, length, &width, &height, &channels) == 1); // using Google test
    std::cout << "length: " << length << std::endl;
    std::cout << "width: " << width << std::endl;
    std::cout << "failure reason: " << stbi_failure_reason() << std::endl;
```

Please find the results below:

```
Actual: false
Expected: true
length: 64
width: -1
failure reason: unknown image type
```

I have also tried with the 2D array. `stb_info` worked successfully where input was image file.

Please let me know what should be expected input data format for this function.

Comment: You tell us, what image format is stored in that byte array?

Comment: It is an unsigned byte.

Comment: @Avi unsigned byte is data type, image format is something else. it's like you said that "an exe format is of unsigned byte format"

Comment: @Avi `unsigned char` is the data type being used for the array itself. But what type of image does the array data represent? The error message is telling you that `stbi_info_from_memory()`  doesn't recognize the type of image you are asking it to return information about. The bytes you have shown do not appear to be for any kind of valid image format.

Comment: I tried this as well. unsigned char data[][4] = {
        {255, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 255, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 255, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}; Can you provide a simple example for this? I couldn't find any example for this in the stb_image github tests.

Comment: @Avi If you already have an array of colors, what do you need STBI for? `stbi_info_from_memory` is for when you have the contents of an image file (e.g. PNG) loaded into a byte array.